# javascript regexp negative lookbehind doesn't match in some case

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

i use node 10.15

i want the expression to match only line2 but not line 1 and line 3

[image]

why this negative lookbehind failed?

```
(?<!月)\d+日(?!后)
```

Comment: hello @gurman, i use node10, think its support. https://node.green/ check lookbehind

Comment: it did not fail in line 1. It picked only the `3日` which satisfies the regular expression.

Comment: Where does it fail? It might not do what you expect it to do but the regex engine is eager to report a match which it evens finds in the first line. Alas not with `23` but with `3` which is totally ok for your expression (`+` = 1 or more characters).

Comment: Why don't you share your Regex build from [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

Add a digit in the negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!月|\d)\d+日(?!后)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly easy. You only have to guarantee, that the match is not preceded by a digit.

```
(?<!月|\d)\d+日(?!后)
------^^^
```

This adds contrast to your RegEx. See [RexEgg](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) for details

[See here for online example](http://regexr.com/47823)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Negative look behind, you should be on EcmaScript2018.

You should put a word boundary `\b` before `\d` in your regex to avoid it matching partially and then it will stop matching your first line. Try this regex,

```
(?<!月)\b\d+日(?!后)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xPF65O/1/)**

Comment: awesome both this and @toto 's anwser are work. but this look best suit.

Comment: where can i find some advanced regex example that i can learn

Comment: @crapthings: The best resource on regex is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) This will give you some good quick overview of regex and also references to great sites.